# How to parse json string starting from the top?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

I have a `json` API that has many optional fields. When I receive this object I need to parse it and add the data to a database. `JSON.parser()` seems to parse the inner most data first which is a waste. I need to start parsing from the top most level first.

Will I need to make a custom string parser or is one available?

Example API:

```
"AddRequest" : {
    "OptionalId" : "",
    "OptionalType" : {
        "Status" : "taken",
        "DateStart" : "21/05/2013",
        "DateEnd" : "21/06/2013",
        "Summary" : "It was really good"
    },
    "OptionalHotels" : [
        {
            "HotelId" : "1",
            "CheckIn" : "21/05/2013", 
            "CheckOut" : "21/06/2013", 
            "Name" : "Hotel Name", 
            "Latitude" : "", 
            "Longitude" : "",
            "City" : "Toronto"
        },
        ... 
    ],
    ...
}
```

---

The code:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data , 
    function(k, v) {
        console.log(k + ':' + v);
    }
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "parse the inner most data first"? The entire JSON text has to be parsed by the parser before you can access it.

Comment: Why are some of the keys in quotes and some aren't?  What do you mean my "inner most data"?  You can't (easily) just parse part of a JSON string.  What happens when you try to call `JSON.parse()` on the entire string?

Comment: @Quentin The parse first returns `Status : taken` key value pair rather than `AddRequest : {...}`

Comment: @andre — Parsing it will return a JavaScript object, not a single key/value pair. (And both JSON and JavaScript objects are unordered)

Comment: @Quentin The parser should return a javascript object parsed from the entire JSON string in one call. Can you show the code you're using to parse the JSON?

Comment: @xdumaine — I'm not andre.

Comment: @Quentin Oops, wrong tag. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `JSON.parse` is a function to *transform* the data.

If you just want to access it, then parse it normally and then access the properties you care about from the return value.

```
var javaScriptObject = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(javaScriptObject.whateverYouWantFirst);
```

Comment: How would I check for optional fields? Without having it throw.

Comment: `if (obj.PotentiallyPresentOptionalField) {}` ??

Comment: @ChristopherW Thanks, undefined seems to evaluate to false. I was not aware until just now.